# GTK mouse side buttons breaks widget hover on X11

Tags: gtk, gtk4

I have a problem with hovering while pressing the back side button (id 8) (or forward (id 9)) on my mouse. If I press the back button while hovering, the widget never stops hovering until I move my mouse off the window or if I click somewhere else inside the window. Even the `EventControllerMotion` doesn't handle the `leave` signal.

Here is a gif of the issue:
[image]

Here is the minimal code that reproduces the issue for me:

```cpp
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

const char css[] =
    "label       {font-size: 20px;}"
    "label:hover {background: red;}";
    
void loadCSS(){
    GdkDisplay* display = gdk_display_get_default();
    GtkCssProvider* provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_string(provider, css);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display(display, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
    g_object_unref(provider);
}

void enter(GtkEventControllerMotion*, gdouble, gdouble, gpointer){
    printf("enter\n");
}

void leave(GtkEventControllerMotion*, gdouble, gdouble, gpointer){
    printf("leave\n");
}

void mback(GtkGestureClick*, gint, gdouble, gdouble, gpointer){
    printf("back\n");
}

void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer){
    GtkApplicationWindow* window = GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW(gtk_application_window_new(app));
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 650, 200);
    
    loadCSS();
    
    // Create label
    GtkWidget* label = gtk_label_new("click with mouse\nback/forward buttons");
    gtk_widget_set_halign(label, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(label, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    
    // Hook 'enter' and 'leave'
    GtkEventController* ctrl = gtk_event_controller_motion_new();
    g_signal_connect(ctrl, "enter", G_CALLBACK(enter), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(ctrl, "leave", G_CALLBACK(leave), NULL);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(label, ctrl);
    
    // Hook 'back' button
    GtkGesture* gest = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gest), 8);
    g_signal_connect(gest, "released", G_CALLBACK(mback), NULL);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(label, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gest));
    
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), label);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){
    GtkApplication* app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.test", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    
    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    
    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}
```

I am using GTK 4.12.4 on Fedora 39 KDE Plasma with X11. **The issue does not appear on wayland.**

How can I fix this? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I don't know GTK4 well enough to be sure, but I'd say it's worth a new issue in bug tracker